# Is there a performance hit by running OpenJDK 17 in debug mode in a container before a debugger is attached?

Tags: java, java-17

We are consolidating and updating our Java deployments, and in that process we would like to be prepared for having to find non-reproducible problems with a running JVM in a container, by having the JVM start in server debug mode (and with Flight Recorder active so we currently do not want J9), where the JVM runs the application while awaiting a debugger connecting.

I believe I have read years back that JVM debug performance had been improved, but I have not been able to located information about how things are now, and whether this might be distribution specific.

Would this perform as well as a JVM not running in debug mode for OpenJDK 17?

Comment: Q: Exactly what kind of potential "performance hit(s)" are you concerned about?  Q: Have you been able to run any comparison tests yourself (e.g. start instances with/without debug mode *OUTSIDE* of a container, and measure with "time", "top", "jstat", VisualVM, etc)?

Comment: CPU usage and memory usage primarily.  I have not done measurements myself yet as I thought this might be something that might also be relevant to others.

Comment: I assume you probably mean configuring your Docker file with something like this: `ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","-agentlib:jdwp","/myapp.jar"]`.  In which case, "No" - I don't believe there's any additional overhead if you don't actually attach the debugger and start setting watches and breakpoints.  But I'd definitely *RUN SOME TESTS*.

Comment: Well, yes, around Java 1.4 times, some performance problems of the JVM debug mode have been fixed. Don’t know why you think that some vaguely remembered out-of-context information matters. The answer to your last question is, no, there is still some potential performance degradation in debug mode. However, the actual question should be, will it run fast enough for you? That’s something, no stranger on the internet can answer for you.